# My ajax code doesn't find my url in my controller (SpringTools Suite)

Tags: java, html, controller, spring-tool-suite

I have a java class named: SeparateRCC.  And now i want to execute it from a button in a web application.

I created a controller class, and my html page (which holds the css and script parts). But when i run the project, and i click the button it gives me a 404 error: POST http://localhost:8080/separate-rcc-ajax 404

Here are my codes:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
  <style>
    //gonna spare you the style
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/separate-rcc-ajax',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
    //alert("Hi");
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    // Another class would go here after everything works on the first button.
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Carga de archivo RCC al AS400</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button id="button1">Separar el archivo RCC</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button id="button2">Mandar los contenidos al AS400</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my controller class:

```
package com.rccClass;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Controlador {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/separate-rcc")
    public String separateRCC() {
        SeparateRCC rcc = new SeparateRCC();
        try {
            rcc.separateRCC(null, null, 0); // Pass null values to use properties file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "index"; // Return the name of the index view
    }

    @PostMapping("/separate-rcc-ajax")
    public @ResponseBody String separateRCCAsync() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            SeparateRCC rcc = new SeparateRCC();
                rcc.separateRCCAsync(null, null, 0); // Pass null values to use properties file
        });
        thread.start();
        return "Processing request...";
    }
}
```

[A view of th console and the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECqgT.png)

As you can see i try running a simple alert to see if the script is being read.
The controller is also (probaly) being read since when i run the application it connects me to the 8080 port, and shows me my index.html
The class itself works, reading a properties file, that's why its being send nulls. The problem itself is that is not finding the /separate-rcc. Or the /separate-rcc-ajax which was a recomendation to

Somethings to note are that although i create the project as a web project, spring starter, and put the dependencies for sping web. It didn't let me create an html file from the sts, i had to go to the folder and create it manually, maybe it has something to do with that? The console in the sts never gives me an error